# deleting a record in many-to-one relation in hibernate is not working

Tags: hibernate

reports.hbm.xml

```
    <hibernate-mapping>
       <class name="com.srdiagnostic.app.bdo.Reports" table="REPORTS" schema="SR">
    <id name="reportsId" type="long">
        <column name="REPORTS_ID" precision="22" scale="0" />
        <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <property name="reportDate" type="date">
        <column name="REPORT_DATE" length="7" />
    </property>
    <many-to-one name="patient" class="com.srdiagnostic.app.bdo.Patient" fetch="select" cascade="all" unique="true" lazy="false">
        <column name="PATIENT_ID" precision="22" scale="0" />
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one name="doctor" class="com.srdiagnostic.app.bdo.Doctor" fetch="select" cascade="all" unique="true" lazy="false">
        <column name="doctor_ID" precision="22" scale="0" />
    </many-to-one>
```

I am able to insert record properly in reports and doctor tables at a time ,but unable to delete a record in reports and Doctor at a time. while deleting a record in reports table it deleting only in reports table but not in Doctor table at a time.

```
   Dao class
    public void deleteReport(Reports report) throws AppException, AppSysException {
    Session  session = SRHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.delete(report);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    System.out.println("Report deleted successfully");
   }
   Reports.java 
   public class Reports  implements java.io.Serializable {
   private Long reportsId;
   private Date reportDate;
   private Patient patient;
   private Doctor doctor;
    //setters&getters }
    Doctor.java
    public class Doctor  implements java.io.Serializable {
   private long doctorId;
   private String doctorName;
   private String place;    
   //setters&getters }
```

Comment: Share your entity bean and dao classes.. error messages if any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"it (is) deleting only in reports table but not in Doctor table at a time."

Relationship exists only on the many side, ie. the report is owning the foreign key referencing associated doctor. You have nothing to delete in doctor table when deleting a report.

the fact is that a doctor may be referenced by many report so you can't trigger a doctor deletion on a single report deletion.

If your aim is to delete a report from a doctor (by removing it from doctor's report collection) delete orphan will do the job (orphanRemoval=true on the OneToMany side of relationship)

Comment: u r  correct doctor is referenced by many reports ,i did wrong.

Comment: but i wanna delete a report called CbpReport it is forigenkey in Reports, when i deleting a record in Reports unable to delete CbpReport.shall i put one-to many relation in Cbpreport.hbm.xml?

Comment: 1 report may have many CbpReport  ? you want the report deletion to trigger associated CbpReport deletion ? => oneToMany CbpReport in report with cascade delete